# Division with denominator sum of values of a variable for period before and after

Tags: loops, sorting, foreach, stata

I want to calculate a division which the numerator is `intraday` variable and the denominator is the aggregate of `daily` values of two days before and after that specific `date` and `name`. This new variable is called `adjusted` as shown in the table below;

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str1 name int date double time byte(Intraday daily) double adjusted
"A" 19693 -1.8934218e+12 1 .         .
"A" 19693   -1.89342e+12 2 3         .
"A" 19694 -1.8934182e+12 3 .         .
"A" 19694 -1.8934164e+12 2 5         .
"A" 19695   -1.89342e+12 2 .  .0952381
"A" 19695 -1.8934182e+12 1 . .04761905
"A" 19695 -1.8934164e+12 1 4 .04761905
"A" 19696 -1.8934146e+12 1 . .04347826
"A" 19696 -1.8934128e+12 3 . .13043478
"A" 19696  -1.893411e+12 3 7 .13043478
"A" 19699 -1.8934218e+12 1 .       .05
"A" 19699   -1.89342e+12 1 2       .05
"A" 19700 -1.8934182e+12 2 . .11111111
"A" 19700 -1.8934164e+12 3 5 .16666667
"A" 19709 -1.8934146e+12 1 . .07692308
"A" 19709 -1.8934128e+12 1 2 .07692308
"A" 19710  -1.893411e+12 2 2         .
"A" 19720 -1.8934218e+12 1 .         .
"A" 19720   -1.89342e+12 1 2         .
"B" 19700 -1.8934182e+12 2 .         .
"B" 19700 -1.8934146e+12 2 .         .
"B" 19700  -1.893411e+12 1 5         .
"B" 19706 -1.8934218e+12 1 .         .
"B" 19706 -1.8934182e+12 1 2         .
"B" 19707 -1.8934128e+12 2 . .13333333
"B" 19707  -1.893411e+12 1 3 .06666667
"B" 19716 -1.8934218e+12 1 1 .08333333
"B" 19717   -1.89342e+12 2 .      .125
"B" 19717 -1.8934182e+12 2 4      .125
"B" 19718 -1.8934128e+12 2 2      .125
"B" 19722 -1.8934218e+12 3 .         .
"B" 19722   -1.89342e+12 2 .         .
"B" 19722 -1.8934182e+12 1 6         .
"B" 19726 -1.8934164e+12 1 .         .
"B" 19726 -1.8934146e+12 1 .         .
"B" 19736 -1.8934128e+12 1 3         .
end
format %tdnn/dd/CCYY date
format %tcHH:MM:SS time
```

Let me give you an example. the value `0.0952381` at date `12/3/2013` in `adjusted` column is `(2/(3+5+4+7+2))`. The value `2` as numerator is `intraday` value at `12/3/2013` and the denominator is the sum of `daily` values for two days before and after plus `daily` of that specific day. For another instance, the `adjusted` value `0.04347826` at date `12/4/2013` is `(1/(3+5+4+7+2))`.

How can I create the variable `adjusted` in table 1?

Comment: This is very unclear. What role does `name` play? Why are there duplicates for many dates? Why are there different values of `intraday` for some `name, date` combinations e.g. `A 19695`?

Comment: I use a high-frequency dataset which is intraday data. `name` is a variable for stocks name. This procedure is repeated for each name and date.

Comment: Please consider, there are some time values for each `date`. `Intraday` is a price for each `name`, `date` and `time`. `Daily` is a sum of `intraday` for each `name` and `date`.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. My fault in not looking carefully enough at the values of `time`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your times are ill-defined.

```
. di %tc -1.8934218e+12
31dec1899 09:30:00
```

That does not bite here. With some struggle to work out your definitions -- you are counting days with defined values, not days as such -- I get this code (using `rangestat` from SSC):

```
bysort name (date daily): gen newdate = sum(daily < .) 
rangestat (count) daily (sum) daily , int(newdate -2 2) by(name) 
gen wanted = Intraday / daily_sum
```

And this result (I see that I should have generated `wanted` as `double`):

```
bysort name : list date Intraday daily adjusted wanted daily_* if daily < ., sep(0) noobs

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-> name = A

  +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |       date   Intraday   daily    adjusted     wanted   daily_~t   daily_~m |
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  12/1/2013          2       3           .   .1666667          3         12 |
  |  12/2/2013          2       5           .   .1052632          4         19 |
  |  12/3/2013          1       4   .04761905    .047619          5         21 |
  |  12/4/2013          3       7   .13043478   .1304348          5         23 |
  |  12/7/2013          1       2         .05        .05          5         20 |
  |  12/8/2013          3       5   .16666667   .1666667          5         18 |
  | 12/17/2013          1       2   .07692308   .0769231          5         13 |
  | 12/18/2013          2       2           .   .1818182          4         11 |
  | 12/28/2013          1       2           .   .1666667          3          6 |
  +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-> name = B

  +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |       date   Intraday   daily    adjusted     wanted   daily_~t   daily_~m |
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  12/8/2013          1       5           .         .1          3         10 |
  | 12/14/2013          1       2           .   .0909091          4         11 |
  | 12/15/2013          1       3   .06666667   .0666667          5         15 |
  | 12/24/2013          1       1   .08333333   .0833333          5         12 |
  | 12/25/2013          2       4        .125       .125          5         16 |
  | 12/26/2013          2       2        .125       .125          5         16 |
  | 12/30/2013          1       6           .   .0666667          4         15 |
  |  1/13/2014          1       3           .   .0909091          3         11 |
  +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your code is perfect. I just change the last line of your code to the following statement: `gen wanted = Intraday / daily_sum if daily_count == 5`

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this (actually, there are probably infinite, but I'm going to show two). The first is to essentially `collapse` the data into a dataset of daily summary stats, and calculate your denominator for each day based on that. The second is to essentially do this with the help of `egen` without ever leaving the original data. I prefer method 1, because it's a bit more obvious and clear what is happening, but to each their own.

First, read in the data and save it as a temporary file. I will also `encode` the "name" variable so we can use time series operators:

```
 * Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
    clear
    input str1 name int date double time byte(Intraday daily) double adjusted
    "A" 19693 -1.8934218e+12 1 .         .
    "A" 19693   -1.89342e+12 2 3         .
    "A" 19694 -1.8934182e+12 3 .         .
    "A" 19694 -1.8934164e+12 2 5         .
    "A" 19695   -1.89342e+12 2 .  .0952381
    "A" 19695 -1.8934182e+12 1 . .04761905
    "A" 19695 -1.8934164e+12 1 4 .04761905
    "A" 19696 -1.8934146e+12 1 . .04347826
    "A" 19696 -1.8934128e+12 3 . .13043478
    "A" 19696  -1.893411e+12 3 7 .13043478
    "A" 19699 -1.8934218e+12 1 .       .05
    "A" 19699   -1.89342e+12 1 2       .05
    "A" 19700 -1.8934182e+12 2 . .11111111
    "A" 19700 -1.8934164e+12 3 5 .16666667
    "A" 19709 -1.8934146e+12 1 . .07692308
    "A" 19709 -1.8934128e+12 1 2 .07692308
    "A" 19710  -1.893411e+12 2 2         .
    "A" 19720 -1.8934218e+12 1 .         .
    "A" 19720   -1.89342e+12 1 2         .
    "B" 19700 -1.8934182e+12 2 .         .
    "B" 19700 -1.8934146e+12 2 .         .
    "B" 19700  -1.893411e+12 1 5         .
    "B" 19706 -1.8934218e+12 1 .         .
    "B" 19706 -1.8934182e+12 1 2         .
    "B" 19707 -1.8934128e+12 2 . .13333333
    "B" 19707  -1.893411e+12 1 3 .06666667
    "B" 19716 -1.8934218e+12 1 1 .08333333
    "B" 19717   -1.89342e+12 2 .      .125
    "B" 19717 -1.8934182e+12 2 4      .125
    "B" 19718 -1.8934128e+12 2 2      .125
    "B" 19722 -1.8934218e+12 3 .         .
    "B" 19722   -1.89342e+12 2 .         .
    "B" 19722 -1.8934182e+12 1 6         .
    "B" 19726 -1.8934164e+12 1 .         .
    "B" 19726 -1.8934146e+12 1 .         .
    "B" 19736 -1.8934128e+12 1 3         .
    end
    format %tdnn/dd/CCYY date
    format %tcHH:MM:SS time


//  Save a temp file
    tempfile master using
    encode name, gen(panel) // Need this for tsset later
    save `master'
```

Next, method 1.

```
*************************************
*   Method 1: Collapse and Merge    *
*************************************


//  Collapse into table of aggregate daily values by day
    collapse (sum) Intraday, by(date panel)

//  Declare data time-series data
    tsset panel date, daily delta(1 day)

//  Calculate aggregate daily values for two days before and after that name-date
    /*  As you will notice here, you do not consistently ACTUALLY have two 
        days before and after each name-date, so they are all missing. Maybe
        in your full data you do, so I have included the appropriate time-series
        operators here (lags [l] and leads [f]).            */
    bysort panel (date): gen denominator_tslags = l2.Intraday + l.Intraday + Intraday + F.Intraday + F2.Intraday

    /*  Alternatively, you could use the values for the days you HAVE before 
        and after, even if the day isn't actually right before. This seems
        to be what you did in your example, but you ignored December 30th for
        name "B".                                                       */
    bysort panel (date): gen denominator = Intraday[_n-2] + Intraday[_n-1] + Intraday + Intraday[_n+1] + Intraday[_n+2]

    rename Intraday daily_calc
    * Save tempfile
    save `using'

//  Merge Using data onto date
    use `master'
    merge m:1 panel date using `using', keepusing(daily_calc denominator)
        assert _merge == 3  // All dates should be merged, even if denominator is missing

//  Generate "adjusted" variable
    gen double adjusted_actual = Intraday / denominator

    * Drop unnecessary variables...
    keep name date time Intraday daily daily_calc adjusted adjusted_actual
        order name date time Intraday daily daily_calc adjusted adjusted_actual

    * Double check that, the adjusted variables are the same...
    gen same = round(adjusted,0.000001) == round(adjusted_actual,0.000001)
```

Now, for method 2:

```
*****************************
*   Method 2: Same Dataset  *
*****************************

    use `master', clear
    tempvar n N
    bysort panel date: egen daily_calc = total(Intraday)

    * For this method, I want a date for ONLY the final time within a date
    bysort panel date: gen `n' = _n
    bysort panel date: gen `N' = _N
    gen ts_date = date if `n' == `N'

    tsset panel ts_date
    sort panel ts_date

    replace panel = . if missing(ts_date)

    * Using Lags

    bysort panel (ts_date): gen denominator_tslags = l2.daily_calc + l.daily_calc + daily_calc + F.daily_calc + F2.daily_calc if !missing(panel)

    * Using pre-post day values
    bysort panel (ts_date): gen denominator = daily_calc[_n-2] + daily_calc[_n-1] + daily_calc + daily_calc[_n+1] + daily_calc[_n+2] if !missing(panel)

/*  Now, the "denominator" values represents 1 value of this denominator every 
    day. We want to set this denominator for every time within the day...   */

    bysort name date (time): egen denominator_full = mean(denominator)

    * Now calculate the ratio...
    gen double adjusted_actual = Intraday / denominator_full

    * Drop unnecessary variables...
    keep name date time Intraday daily daily_calc adjusted adjusted_actual
        order name date time Intraday daily daily_calc adjusted adjusted_actual

    * Double check that, the adjusted variables are the same...
    gen same = round(adjusted,0.000001) == round(adjusted_actual,0.000001)
```

Comment: Much good general technique here. `rangestat` permits some shortening.